# How to find the sum of elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pseudocode

I have a 12 * 12 square array in C++ (the image given below). Now I have three problems;

1. How Do I go about finding the sum of the elements in the yellow boxes (anti-diagonal)?
2. Assuming that I am constrained to using a single iteration to transverse the yellow diagonal, what pseudo code can I implement using a program code in C++, to find the sum of the elements?
3. What general Formula can I use to find the sum of the elements in the yellow boxes (anti-diagonal) of a square array of any size (that is, regardless of the number of equal rows and columns)?

[image]

Comment: what have you trried? did it work? why?

Comment: start from (Row1, Col12), in each iteration, increase Row, decrease Col..

Comment: `int sum = 0; for (int i = 0, j = total_cols - 1; i < total_rows && j >= 0; i++, j--) sum += arr[i][j];`

Comment: @kiner_shah please which question does your suggestion answer? It seems really helpful.

Comment: Write down the indices of all the elements you want to sum, first with a 2x2 matrix, then 3x3, then perhaps 4x4, and you will discover a pattern that gives you the general solution.

Comment: @Presh_K7, all questions!

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for this downvote? Because i found it difficult to come up with any conclusive suggestion in the first place.

Comment: please one question per question, though it seems your 3 questions are all the same just formulated differently. Also I wonder what is the relevance of the c++ tag when there is no code and you want a language-agnostic answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single iteration over the length of the array (starting a 0), and sum all the elements with the index `[i][length_of_array - 1 - i]`

Comment: shouldn't it be `-1` ?The first element (`i==0`) is  `[0][length_of_array-1]`